# Contacts from Address Book Disappeared

Tags: macos, imac, software-update, contacts

I just installed El Capitan (I used to have Lion OS X), and I lost my address book. So I googled about it and I can restore them from my time machine. I did that but the file can't be opened in the address book app. What can I do to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you sync contacts over iCloud? If you do then you can find them on iCloud.com and be able to restore that way. BTW the app is called Contacts now, different name.

Answer (score 1):

If your contacts were connected to an account (e.g., iCloud or Exchange), you may need to re-authenticate after an OS upgrade. Go to System Preferences > Internet Accounts and make sure Contacts for the account you use is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found my data appeared instantly when I disabled facebook's Card DAV account in preferences.